# How to get posts with a metadata numeric key greater than X?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm trying to add a "Highlighted" section for each category on my website. This will be located in a page, using a shortcode. I'm going to add a new post metadata key which will be a number from 0 to 100. Each "Highlighted" section will list the posts in that category which have a score higher than 50, in descending order of score.

Looking in the WordPress Codex, I saw that get_posts accepts "meta_key" and "meta_value" as arguments. However, they seem to be specific values, whereas I would like to add a "greater than 50" condition for the "meta_key".

How would one get those "greater than 50" posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of *meta query* in `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`:

```
'meta_query' => [
    [
        'key'     => 'score',
        'value'   => 50,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>=',
    ],
],
```

would generate the following SQL `WHERE` part:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'score' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '50'
```

This kind of *ordering*:

```
'orderby'  => [ 
    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 
    'title'          => 'ASC' 
],
```

would generate:

```
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, wp_posts.post_title ASC
```

If we use the syntax [defined here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/), with the meta query array index as `score_clause`, then

```
'orderby'  => [ 
    'score_clause'  => 'DESC', 
    'title'         => 'ASC' 
],
```

would generate:

```
ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC, wp_posts.post_title ASC
```